# How to Resize and Reposition 'ImageView' by Screen Scale remain its ratio

Tags: java, android, imageview

*Text Code of MainActivity.java and activity_main.xml exist at the bottom of the article*

I am going to set Images that have the same ratio (16:9) to ImageView,
But I met up with a small problem.

I want to set My `ImageView` remain 16:9 ratio, which of the picture being handed over(1920 * 1080)

> **if I use `wrap_content`,** it remains ratio of the given picture,    But
>   I can't resize the size of `ImageView`.
>   [image]

.

> **if I use fixed numbers that remain 16:9 ratio like 400dp * 225dp**
>   I can resize the size I want, and modify the position by Screen scale by
>   using `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=` and
>   `app:layout_constraintVertical_bias=`
>
> But in other Device, the Size of `ImageView` is **too small** or **too big** for its Screen Space.
>   because the value is fixed
>   [image]
>   [image]

So, I Want to set `ImageView` Size and Position by Device's Screen Scale with remaining its ratio(16:9)
How can I do it?

I've looked at a number of questions, but I've found a way "to match the imageView ratio to the picture" not "to set the size of ImageView relative to the size of the screen" cause my poor at searching.

Is there any method way to express as follows?
this is not real code, it is just pseudo-code to explain easily what I really want to make.

```
android:layout_width="wrapcontent * 0.8"
android:layout_height="wrapcontent * 0.8"  //<!-- same as "layout_width * 9 / 16 " because ratio of give picture will be always 16 : 9 -->

app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias=" ((Screen_width - ImageView_width) / 2) / 100 " //<!-- pseudo percentage that to stay in Screen's center -->
app:layout_constraintVertical_bias= "0.3" //<!-- pseudo percentage that to stay in Screen's custom upper part-->
```

I apologize for the confusion in your explanation and hope you have a peaceful day.
MainActivity.The code for java and activity_main.xml is below.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.catexample;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // I Want to Resize and Reposition 'ImageView' by Screen Scale remain its ratio( 16 : 9)
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.kitti_DD);
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/kitti_DD"
        android:layout_width="400dp"
        android:layout_height="225dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.1"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.3"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"

        app:srcCompat="@drawable/kittisaurus_dd" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**kittisaurus_dd.jpg**
[image]

ps.The cute cat's name used as an example is **DD** and it originated from a video of a [크집사](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCkuA_gDjISfGgbdp02BUwyQ) ,not 크림히어로즈.

Thank you from the bottom of my heart for reading the long article!

Comment: try setting seting  layout_height="0" , layout_width="0" then it will match the constraints, then you need to twitch the constraints do get what you want, like adjusting the bias etc, but try it.

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan Thank you from the bottom of my heart for your help. In this way, the ratio remains at same, but, um... ImageView is full of screen size. 

Comment: yes because the constraints are pulling it equally by all sides , you can try attaching imageview to guidelines, you should also show excepted result , maybe by just drawing it on paper

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan Oh, I forgot about that. while agonizing over what I have tried I forgot the most important thing. Thank you for your good opinion and I will make sure to apply the next question! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width and height to 0dp and add the `app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio` attribute and set its value to your desired aspect ratio, e.g.: 4:3, 16:9, etc.

Comment: Thank you from the bottom of my heart for your help. In this way, the ratio remains at 16:9, but, um... ImageView is full of screen size. 

Is there any way to change the size of the ImageView to about 80 percent?!

Comment: No worries mate! Add a guideline where you want your ImageView to be limited to then constrain your ImageView to the guideline. Have a look at this post I wrote on Medium about ConstraintLayout, hope it helps https://medium.com/@92alanc/the-ultimate-view-group-constraintlayout-e0598d2e1a05
Please don't forget to accept the answer

Comment: Wow, this is the post that I was looking for regarding UI... Thank you so much. I will read your precious article carefully and find out how to solve the problem again!

Comment: nice article Alan , @J4BEZ if you like videos can learn from there too -> https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrnPJCHvNZuA80lNWNCLICR3qYzhw3iPI

Comment: @AbhinavChauhan That's some golden information! I heartily thank you